# Failed to load data from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, mapreduce, apache-pig, amazon-ec2

I launched two m1.medium nodes on amazon ec2 for executing my pig script, but looks like it failed at the first line (even before MapReduce start): `raw = LOAD 's3n://uw-cse-344-oregon.aws.amazon.com/btc-2010-chunk-000' USING TextLoader as (line:chararray);`

The error message I got:

```
2015-02-04 02:15:39,804 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2015-02-04 02:15:39,821 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient - Default number of map tasks: null
2015-02-04 02:15:39,822 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient - Setting default number of map tasks based on cluster size to : 20
... (omitted)
2015-02-04 02:18:40,955 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2015-02-04 02:18:40,956 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_201502040202_0002 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2015-02-04 02:18:40,956 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2015-02-04 02:18:40,997 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: Java heap space
2015-02-04 02:18:40,997 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2015-02-04 02:18:40,997 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: HadoopVersion    PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features 1.0.3  0.11.1.1-amzn   hadoop 2015-02-04 02:15:32  2015-02-04 02:18:40 GROUP_BY

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201502050202_0002   ngroup,raw,triples,tt   GROUP_BY,COMBINER   Message: Job failed! Error - # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201502050202_0002_m_000022

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "s3n://uw-cse-344-oregon.aws.amazon.com/btc-2010-chunk-000"

Output(s):

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0
```

I think the code should be fine since I have ever successfully loaded other data with the same syntax, and the link to `s3n://uw-cse-344-oregon.aws.amazon.com/btc-2010-chunk-000` looks valid. I suspect it might be related to some of my EC2 settings, but not sure how to investigate further or narrow down the problem. Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Java heap space" error message gives some clues. Your files seem to be quite large (~2GB). Make sure that you have enough memory for each task runner to read the data.

Comment: yeah...looks like that's the root cause, looks like m1.medium is not enough for this dataset. Thank you for shedding some light on it!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was currently solved by changing my node from **m1.medium** to **m3.large** , thanks for the good hint from @Nat as he pointed out the error message regarding with *java heap space*. I'll update more details later.